# Django keeps making extra migration files in the virtual environment

Tags: django, django-migrations

This is partially linked to the following query, but is slightly different.

[Django startapp producing too many files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59683282/django-startapp-producing-too-many-files)

Basically, I have re-installed Django and updated it to version 2.1.1

I don't seem to get extra number replica's within my main app's, however when I run migrations, Django seems to put a set of migrations into my virtual environment.   These tend to be called things like admin, auth, contenttypes and sessions.

Every now and then Django seems to create extra number files within these migrations inside the virtual environment, which muck's up my migrations.   I can delete and re-create the virtual environment and so fix the problem quickly, but I am concerned that there is a bit of a problem, because it is happening regularly.

Any suggestions ?